# How to type gas sign and equality sign in chemfig?

Tags: xetex, chemfig

I want to type some inorganic chemistry equations and some organic chemistry, but I can't type =, ^(means that there is gas) or |(means that there is solid). For example, how to type 2NaClO = 2NaCl + O_2^ and CH_3CHO + 2Ag(NH_3)_2OH -> CH_3COONH_4 + 2Ag | + 3NH_3 ^ + H_2O in chemfig?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I'm not a chemist and I suppose chemists know what you mean, but anyways, if you included a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) of how you use `chemfig` and a picture of the desired output?

Comment: Using arrows to denote the state of aggregation is considered an obsolete practice and should be avoided unless you are replicating an old textbook or manuscript. Currently, IUPAC recommends to enclose abbreviated state symbol in brackets, e.g. O₂(g) or Ag(s), **not** O₂↑ or Ag↓.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to typeset chemical equations, then I suggest using the [`mhchem`](ftp://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/mhchem/mhchem.pdf) package. The [`chemfig`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/chemfig/chemfig_doc_en.pdf) package is intended more for drawing two-dimensional chemical figures.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\begin{document}

\ce{2NaClO {=} 2NaCl + O2 ^}

\ce{CH3CHO + 2Ag(NH3)2OH -> CH3COONH4 + 2Ag v + 3NH3 ^ + H2O}

\end{document}
```

[image]

---

If you truly want literal `^` and `|` symbols instead of `↑` and `↓` arrows, then try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\def\mycaret{{\char`\^}}
\def\mypipe{{\char`|}}

\begin{document}

\ce{2NaClO {=} 2NaCl + O2 \mycaret}

\ce{CH3CHO + 2Ag(NH3)2OH -> CH3COONH4 + 2Ag \mypipe + 3NH3 \mycaret + H2O}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Isn't normally a down arrow used for precipitates (`\ce{v}`) and an up arrow for gas (`\ce{^}`)? This is at least the reason for mhchem's default behaviour, I think... BTW: the chemformula package does similar things...

Comment: "The symbol [`\ce{v}`] indicates formation of a precipate; the symbol [`\ce{^}`] indicates the formation of gas." from [Organic Chemistry](https://books.google.de/books?id=JasIAAAAQBAJ&lpg=PA576&ots=uf_yhaFyAE&dq=precipitate&pg=PA272#v=onepage&q=precipitate)

Comment: You can leave out all those underscrores. `\ce{CH_3CHO}` has a wrong visual grouping. You could simply write `\ce{CH3CHO}`. So it could be `\ce{CH3CHO + 2Ag(NH3)2OH -> CH3COONH4 + 2Ag v + 3NH3 ^ + H2O}`.

Comment: @mhchem Thanks. As I'm not a chemist, I had no idea that's what OP was asking for.

Comment: @hftf For the record, I am no chemist either. I am interested in chemical typography and in the usability of formula input, but I do not actually understand the meaning of these formulae.